# How to resolve an incomplete svn check-out in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, svn-checkout

I am trying to checkout my project. After 80% it not moving forward and showing just checking out.

So, I closed Eclipse and restarted because checkout process not closing even I click on terminated icon. That's ok. I tried multiple times in multiple ways.

How to check-out remaining 20% instead of starting from first?

Comment: I don't know eclipse, but you may try `svn cleanup`

Comment: What happens when you try to perform a checkout outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I don't have svn-client installed.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 steps should solve your problem:

1. perfom `svn cleanup` to remove the lock, which is probably present because of interrupting the checkout
2. perform `svn update`. This should checkout the remaining 20%